# How does processes synchronization using signals work?

Tags: c, signals

I've recently finished Section 10 (Signals) of "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment" (3rd edition) and I've come across a piece of code I don't entirely understand:

```
#include "apue.h"

static volatile sig_atomic_t sigflag; /* set nonzero by sig handler */
static sigset_t newmask, oldmask, zeromask;

static void
sig_usr(int signo)  /* one signal handler for SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 */
{
    sigflag = 1;
}

void
TELL_WAIT(void)
{
    if (signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("signal(SIGUSR1) error");
    if (signal(SIGUSR2, sig_usr) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("signal(SIGUSR2) error");
    sigemptyset(&zeromask);
    sigemptyset(&newmask);
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR2);

    /* Block SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2, and save current signal mask */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask) < 0)
        err_sys("SIG_BLOCK error");
}

void
TELL_PARENT(pid_t pid)
{
    kill(pid, SIGUSR2);     /* tell parent we're done */
}

void
WAIT_PARENT(void)
{
    while (sigflag == 0)
        sigsuspend(&zeromask);  /* and wait for parent */
    sigflag = 0;

    /* Reset signal mask to original value */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
        err_sys("SIG_SETMASK error");
}

void
TELL_CHILD(pid_t pid)
{
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);         /* tell child we're done */
}

void
WAIT_CHILD(void)
{
    while (sigflag == 0)
        sigsuspend(&zeromask);  /* and wait for child */
    sigflag = 0;

    /* Reset signal mask to original value */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
        err_sys("SIG_SETMASK error");
}
```

The routines above are used (as you certainly know) to synchronize processes using signals. Although I understand every single line on its own, I can't see (understand) the big picture. The code itself is used it the following scenario: to avoid a race condition in our program, after we fork(), we make the child process TELL_PARENT and WAIT_PARENT, and then we do the same to the parent with TELL_CHILD and WAIT_CHILD. My questions are:

1.) How can a child communicate with its parent through a variable while both of them work with their own set (copy) of variables? Is it because the child doesn't modify sigflag directly but through a signal handler (the same goes for the parent)?
2.) Why do we need to block SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 and then unblock it with sigprocmask?

A program that uses three of those routines could be (taken from the book):

```
#include "apue.h"

static void charatatime(char *);

int
main(void)
{
    pid_t   pid;

    TELL_WAIT();

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        err_sys("fork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        WAIT_PARENT();      /* parent goes first */
        charatatime("output from child\n");
    } else {
        charatatime("output from parent\n");
        TELL_CHILD(pid);
    }
    exit(0);
}

static void
charatatime(char *str)
{
    char    *ptr;
    int     c;

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);           /* set unbuffered */
    for (ptr = str; (c = *ptr++) != 0; )
        putc(c, stdout);
}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** They are not communicating through "variable" - the sole communication facility used here is `kill` function. We "tell" things by invoking `kill`, we "wait" to be told with `sigsuspend`. `sig_flag` is not shared, it's a local state of each process, and it says whether *this particular process* has been "told" by the other.

**2)** Were the signals not blocked prior to `fork`, the parent process could send the signal to the child before the child has started waiting for it. That is, the timeline could be like that:

- fork
- parent gets the time slice, sends signal to the child with `kill`
- child gets the time slice, and waits for the signal

But this signal **has already been delivered**, and so waits indefinitely. Therefore, we must ensure the signal is not delivered to the child process before it starts the waiting loop. To this end, we block it before `fork`, and **atomically** unblock it and start waiting for it. Atomicity is the key; required invariant cannot be achieved with this operation performed as two independent steps, as the signal could be delivered inbetween.

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time to answer but I still have trouble understanding the issues mentioned in my question. Let's assume that we're executing the aforesaid program. As I understand, when we are in the child process the value of sigflag is 0 (initialized with the static keyword). Then in WAIT_PARENT we're waiting for it to change to 1. But as we aren't changing it ourselves (the signal handler does) how can it change in our address space? In other words, whose variable (sigflag) does the signal handler really change?

Comment: The signal handler is not external concept. It's a property of the process, that child simply inherited. Both parent and child have independent signal handlers. Initially both are set to `sig_usr`, but if we change the handler in the child it will not affect the parent and vice versa. Handler is invoked in the address space of the process that the signal is delivered to.

Comment: To explicitly answer the final question of your comment: both, depending on the signal's recipient. When parent "tells child", the signal is delivered to the child process, and the handler is invoked in the child process' address space. Then, when the child "tells parent", signal is delivered to the parent, the handler is invoked in the parent's address space and so acts upon parent's `sig_flag`.

Comment: Although I'm supposed to avoid comments like "thanks", well, thanks! :)

Comment: While I already appreciate your previous answer, there is still one more aspect of this code that bugs me. Why should we care if the signal gets delivered to the other process before it starts waiting for it (I mean, in this particular example)? Let's imagine that we don't block SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 and the parent sends the signal before we start waiting for it with sigsuspend. Our signal handler changes the value of sigflag immidiately, before we enter the while loop. Therefore we don't call sigsuspend at all (logically, we don't have anything to wait for) and go straight to sigprocmask.

Comment: Okay, perhaps my answer was not that clear after all ;) If the signal is delivered before BOTH `while` condition check and pause, we're fine. If it's delivered after both, we're fine. If it's delivered after the loop condition has been checked, but before the process started waiting (i.e. sleeping) for the signal, we're screwed, since we don't know it has been delivered (when we checked, it hadn't been yet), and we start waiting for it.

Comment: That's where the *atomicity* comes in to rescue - with `sigprocmask` the signal couldn't have possibly been delivered in this unfortunate time window, because it's blocked until `sigprocmask` call.
By the way, it's nice to know some people actually read Stevens with the desire to understand all the intricacies :)

Comment: Okey. Now I get it (hopefully;). Thanks again for your time. :)